# Minecraft add new potion effects from custom potion effect

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Currently trying to create a potion effect that once it runs out of time, applies other potion effects to the player. Seemed simple enough yet I found a few errors and bugs trying to accomplish this,

Directly trying to add the effect

```
    @Override
    public void performEffect(EntityLivingBase entity, int amplifier){
        if (entity instanceof EntityPlayer)
        {
            EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer)entity;
            if(player != null){
                if(player.getActivePotionEffect(PotionRegistry.effectBuzz) != null){
                int duraction = player.getActivePotionEffect(PotionRegistry.effectBuzz).getDuration();
                    if(duration <= 2){
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(MobEffects.WEAKNESS, 1200));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Needless to say this produces this error

> [16:10:04] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
>       net.minecraft.util.ReportedException: Ticking player
>         at net.minecraft.network.NetworkSystem.networkTick(NetworkSystem.java:212)
>   ~[NetworkSystem.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.updateTimeLightAndEntities(MinecraftServer.java:807)
>   ~[MinecraftServer.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tick(MinecraftServer.java:688)
>   ~[MinecraftServer.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.tick(IntegratedServer.java:156)
>   ~[IntegratedServer.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:537)
>   [MinecraftServer.class:?]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
>       Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>         at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>         at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>         at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.updatePotionEffects(EntityLivingBase.java:650)
>   ~[EntityLivingBase.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.onEntityUpdate(EntityLivingBase.java:383)
>   ~[EntityLivingBase.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:436) ~[Entity.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.onUpdate(EntityLivingBase.java:2144)
>   ~[EntityLivingBase.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer.onUpdate(EntityPlayer.java:260)
>   ~[EntityPlayer.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayerMP.onUpdateEntity(EntityPlayerMP.java:345)
>   ~[EntityPlayerMP.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.network.NetHandlerPlayServer.update(NetHandlerPlayServer.java:174)
>   ~[NetHandlerPlayServer.class:?]
>         at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.handshake.NetworkDispatcher$1.update(NetworkDispatcher.java:216)
>   ~[NetworkDispatcher$1.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.network.NetworkManager.processReceivedPackets(NetworkManager.java:309)
>   ~[NetworkManager.class:?]
>         at net.minecraft.network.NetworkSystem.networkTick(NetworkSystem.java:197)
>   ~[NetworkSystem.class:?]
>         ... 5 more

Where as if I run this in a tick event

In CommonProxy

```
MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new EventManager());
```

And then For the EventManager itself

```
public class EventManager {

public static PotionEffect potion = new PotionEffect(MobEffects.WEAKNESS, 1200);
public static PotionEffect potion2 = new PotionEffect(MobEffects.HUNGER, 600);
public static PotionEffect potion3 = new PotionEffect(MobEffects.UNLUCK, 1200);

@SubscribeEvent
public void onTick(WorldTickEvent event){
    EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer;
    World world = Minecraft.getMinecraft().theWorld;
    if(player != null){
        boolean hasEffect = player.isPotionActive(PotionRegistry.effectBuzz);
        int applyIt = 0;

        if(hasEffect){
            applyIt = 1;
        } else if(!player.isPotionActive(potion.getPotion()) && applyIt == 1){
            applyIt = 2;
        } else {
            applyIt = 0;
        }

        if(player != null && applyIt == 2){
            player.addPotionEffect(potion);
        }
    }
}
```

}

This works, yet the effects are infinite.

Comment: Can you schedule a task to add the negative potion effects right after you added your positiver potion effects?

Comment: Something in the line of BukkitRunnables

Answer (score 2):

You're performing your action whilst the potion effects are being looped. This is akin to modifying an array whilst iterating it. Don't do that.

Also, don't perform actions like potion effects client side.
The ONLY thing to do client side is graphics and user input/output.

Things like potions must be handled on the server, otherwise the server will overwrite your actions on the next update packet.

Just set a flag in your ExtendPlayer entity, and then onTick or player update event check for that flag existance and then add the potions.

```
@Override
public void performEffect(EntityLivingBase entity, int amplifier){
    if (entity instanceof EntityPlayer)
    {
        EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer)entity;
        if(player != null){
            if(player.getActivePotionEffect(PotionRegistry.effectBuzz) != null){
            int duraction = player.getActivePotionEffect(PotionRegistry.effectBuzz).getDuration();
                if(duration <= 2){
                    ExtendedPlayer ePlayer = ExtendedPlayer.get(player);
                    ePlayer.enableBuzz();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something akin to your Extended player

```
public class ExtendedPlayer implements IExtendedEntityProperties {

     ... Extended player setup here

     protected boolean startBuzz = false;

     public void enableBuzz() 
     {
          this.startBuzz = true;
     }
     public static final ExtendedPlayer get(EntityPlayer player) {
        return (ExtendedPlayer) player.getExtendedProperties("MuddymansExtendedPlayer");
    }

    public EntityPlayer getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }

    /**
    * Updates anything that needs to be updated each tick
    * NOT called automatically, so you must call it yourself from LivingUpdateEvent or a TickHandler
    */
    public void onUpdate() {
        if(!player.worldObj.isRemote) {
            if(this.enableBuzz) {
                Player player = this.getPlayer()
                player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(MobEffects.WEAKNESS, 1200));
                player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(MobEffects.HUNGER, 600));
                player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(MobEffects.UNLUCK, 1200));
                this.startBuzz = false;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Call the exteded player update event from an event handler

```
 @SubscribeEvent
 public void livingTick(final LivingUpdateEvent event) {
        if (event.entity != null && event.entity instanceof EntityPlayer) {
            if(!event.entity.isDead) {
                ExtendedPlayer.get((EntityPlayer)event.entity).onUpdate();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have included more information, I don't have an extended player class, I'm not exactly new to coding or Minecraft modding, I just haven't done much related to potion effects and how they interact with the player.

What I showed you before was in fact an EventManager

I'll update the question to reflect it.

Comment: Just add an extended player class. It's trivally easy, especially in the newer minecraft versions `public class ExtendedPlayer implements ICapabilitySerializable {` There are a lot of tutorials, but it will seriously help you track individual things done to players and a central place where to serialize and deserialize player statusses. Also, don't add new potion effects from within a potion effect. If you don't want to use an extended player, you'll have to make an arraylist where you store the player entity and then empty that arraylist in the event handler.

Comment: I highly recommend using Capabilities, provided you are on 1.11 or newer. (The very last few versions of 1.10 also have it, but its not a sure thing).

Comment: 1.10 has capabilities too. But they function badically the same